# How to recover an accidentally deleted package from NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

I accidentally deleted a package that had a number of classes in it from my NetBeans project. I can't find it from **History > Revert Deleted**. Is there a way to recover the package and its content?

Answer (score 1):

Create the package with the same name again and then your classes will be shown under History / Revert Deleted.

[edit]
And for the next time do yourself a favor and use some version control like Subversion, GIT or something alike.